# Building a dictionary from directory structure

Tags: python, tree

I'm trying to build a dictionary that looks like this:

```
nodes = {
    'var': {
        'type': 'd',
        'full_path': '/var'
        'active': True
        'www': {
            'type': 'd',
            'full_path': '/var/www',
            'active': True
            'index.html': {
                'type': 'f',
                'full_path': '/var/www/index.html',
                'active': False
            }
        'log': {
            'type': 'd',
            'full_path': '/var/log',
            'active': False
        }
    }
    'srv': {
        'type': 'd',
        'full_path': '/srv',
        'active': True
    }
}
```

I need it to be built by two pieces... The first needs to be from the file system where everything is 'active'. The second needs to come from a listing of full paths of files where everything is inactive.

So...

```
nodes = {}
for f, d, r in os.walk(root_path):
    # append active items to nodes
for f in os.system(command_that_gets_files)
    # append inactive items to nodes; not overwriting active
```

I'm sure I'm missing details...

Comment: I'd suggest using in stead of the subdirectory names as keys, a single key 'items' which maps on a list of subdirectories. You'll avoid some annoying clashes.

Comment: The way you formulate it, the inactive nodes will be unexisting files?

Comment: I'm open to that. I still have no idea how I would write it. This is for an overly-complicated web application for doing file restorations that I've been tasked with creating. [active means it exists on the files system, inactive means the files have been erased from the system but exists in archives -- this is a backup server that also has tape backups]

Comment: Are you dealing with nginx config or something?

Comment: How to read the filesystem (active files) and how to parse the listing (inactive files) seems like two questions to me. If you still need help with the latter, I suggest you post another question.

Comment: Probably correct. I'll ask another question for that part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way to get the active files. I found it easier to recurse than to use `os.walk()`'s iterative data. You may uncomment the `result['stat']` line if you need to preserve more information than file type.

Every file has a dict entry like:

```
filename : { 'active' : True,
             'full_path' = '/path/to/filename',
             'type' : 'f' }
```

Every directory has a dict entry like:

```
dirname : { 'active' : True,
            'full_path' = '/path/to/dirname',
             'type' : 'd',
             items = { 'itemname' : {...}, ... } }
```

Here you go:

```
import sys
import os
from stat import *
import pprint

def PathToDict(path):
    st = os.stat(path)
    result = {}
    result['active'] = True
    #result['stat'] = st
    result['full_path'] = path
    if S_ISDIR(st.st_mode):
        result['type'] = 'd'
        result['items'] = {
            name : PathToDict(path+'/'+name)
            for name in os.listdir(path)}
    else:
        result['type'] = 'f'
    return result


pprint.pprint(PathToDict(sys.argv[1]))
```

Result:

```
{'active': True,
 'full_path': '/tmp/x',
 'items': {'var': {'active': True,
                   'full_path': '/tmp/x/var',
                   'items': {'log': {'active': True,
                                     'full_path': '/tmp/x/var/log',
                                     'items': {},
                                     'type': 'd'},
                             'www': {'active': True,
                                     'full_path': '/tmp/x/var/www',
                                     'items': {'index.html': {'active': True,
                                                              'full_path': '/tmp/x/var/www/index.html',
                                                              'type': 'f'}},
                                     'type': 'd'}},
                   'type': 'd'}},
 'type': 'd'}
```

Comment: How would I use this to loop over multiple listings? (get all of /var/ into the dict)

Comment: `var_dict = PathToDict('/var')` will get all descendents of `/var` into one dict.

Comment: This relies on the system actually having the files... In the second part, it's a list of files that don't actually exist on the system...

Comment: Yes, this produces a dict of existing files.

Comment: I don't think this works on symlinks. For purpose of fixing it, I replaced `S_ISDIR` with `os.path.isdir`