# How to create dictionary or list from tree structure in Python?

Tags: python-2.7

How to get path from child to parent?

```
Udo
├── Marc
│   └── Lian
└── Dan
    ├── Jet
    ├── Jan
    └── Joe
```

Comment: How is this tree structure actually represented? How do you build it?

Comment: This is just an example.  I have some data that are in tree structure. I need get the path from child to parent..

Comment: I mean, are these data stored in a variable? What is the type of this variable? Or are these in a file? Or in a database?

Comment: We can assign this as either file or variable..

Comment: The point is: we dont know where to start if we dont know the primitive data structure of this tree you posted

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Building a dictionary from directory structure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19522004/building-a-dictionary-from-directory-structure)